# Android: what is wrong with my query?

Tags: android, sqlite

DataBaseAdapter methods:

```
public long insertRecordCategory(String name, String device)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(NAME, name);
        cv.put(DEVICE, device);

        if(!updateRecord(cv, device))
                return db.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
        else return 0;
    }

    private boolean updateRecord(ContentValues values, String device) {
        return db.update(TABLE, values, DEVICE + "=" + device, null) > 0;
    }

    public String isDeviceRegistered(String device) {
        String [] coloane = {NAME, DEVICE};
        Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE, coloane, DEVICE + "=" + device, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c == null)
            return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NAME));
    }
```

When I'm trying to call: isDeviceRegistered it says:

`05-25 16:44:47.170: E/AndroidRuntime(14504): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":02": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _name, _device FROM FriendsTable WHERE _device=22:02:af:db:24:9a`

When calling update it says:

```
05-25 17:36:55.190: E/AndroidRuntime(469): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":02": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE FriendsTable SET device=?,name=? WHERE device=22:02:af:db:24:9a
```

And this update method is the same one form another project where it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals in SQL need to be in `'single quotes'`. However, it's better to use bind args instead. Replace

```
DEVICE + "=" + device, null
```

with

```
DEVICE + "=?", new String[] { device }
```

Comment: The same applies to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `'` placeholder.

Replace

```
DEVICE + "=" + device
```

with

```
DEVICE + "='" + device + "'"
```